# How can I use R to see the error metrics in HydroGOF？

Tags: r, hydrogof

under the two conditions of "Simulated" and "Measured" (See the image),

[image]

I want to calculate some error metrics such as Nash-Sutcliffe efficiency (NSE) or root mean square error (RMSE), but I don't know how to code the command. 
There are **728** simulated values, while measured values only **30**.
Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

```
library(readxl)
library(hydroGOF)
library(zoo)
X0_40cm <- read_excel("C:/Rstudy/For_10-40cm.xlsx")
data(X0_40cm)
```

Comment: Length of simulated and measured should be same and put the measured and simulated column side by side. If you can provide the data in `dput()` format, I can help you out.

Comment: That would be so good! Thank you!

Comment: > dput(my_data)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1507852800, 1507939200, 1508025600, 1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 1508371200, 1508457600, 1508544000, 1508630400, 1508716800, 1508803200, 1508889600, 1508976000), class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Simulated = c(0.23375, 0.23175, 0.231, 0.2305, 0.2405, 0.24, 0.2385, 0.23675, 0.2355, 0.234, 0.23225, 0.23075, 0.2295, 0.2285), Measured = c(NA, 0.273, NA, NA, 0.21311677200277, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.229871184500008, NA, NA, 0.242, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to calculate `NSE` and `rmse` with `hydroGOF` package

```
library(hydroGOF)
NSE(df$Simulated, df$Measured, na.rm = T)
#[1] -37.85747
rmse(df$Simulated, df$Measured, na.rm = T)
#[1] 0.02561592
```

## Data

```
df = structure(list(Date = structure(c(1507852800, 1507939200, 1508025600,
1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 1508371200, 1508457600, 1508544000,
1508630400, 1508716800, 1508803200, 1508889600, 1508976000), 
class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
Simulated = c(0.23375, 0.23175, 0.231, 0.2305, 0.2405, 0.24, 0.2385, 0.23675, 0.2355, 0.234, 0.23225, 0.23075, 0.2295, 0.2285), 
Measured = c(NA, 0.273, NA, NA, 0.21311677200277, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.229871184500008, NA, NA, 0.242, NA)), 
row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## Update

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1507852800, 1507939200, 1508025600, 1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 1508371200, 1508457600, 1508544000, 1508630400, 1508716800, 1508803200, 1508889600, 1508976000), class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Simulated = c(0.23375, 0.23175, 0.231, 0.2305, 0.2405, 0.24, 0.2385, 0.23675, 0.2355, 0.234, 0.23225, 0.23075, 0.2295, 0.2285), Measured = c(NA, 0.273, NA, NA, 0.21311677200277, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.229871184500008, NA, NA, 0.242, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
View(df)
library(dplyr)
library(hydroGOF)
library(zoo)

Simulated <- df$Simulated
Measured <- df$Measured
Date <- df$Date

ggof(sim=Simulated, obs=Measured, na.rm = TRUE, dates = Date, date.fmt = "%Y-%m-%d",,
     pt.style = "ts", ftype = "o", FUN,
     stype="default",
     gof.leg = TRUE, digits=2,
     gofs=c("ME", "MAE", "RMSE", "NRMSE", "PBIAS", "RSR", "rSD", "NSE", "mNSE",
            "rNSE", "d", "md", "rd", "r", "R2", "bR2", "KGE", "VE"),
     col = c("black", "red"),
     main="Try", #Provide the chart title here
     xlab = "Time", #Change the x-axis title here
     ylab=c("Q, [m3/s]"), #Change the y-axis title here
     lwd = c(2, 1), #To change the line width
     cex = c(1, 2)) #To change the size of the points
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I stil meet one slight problem about changing the size of line and point separately. Also I failed to change the title of X-, Y- axis and main title. The below is the code I used. Could you please help me check maybe?

Comment: I left the code in a new post since it's a little bit long. Thank you  again!

Comment: @LINKANG see my update. If you need any further help regarding this and don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I have accepted the answer:) and I have one last question"How can the Y-axis be changed to percent？" Thank you!

Comment: @LINKANG I didn't get you. What do you mean by "How can the Y-axis be changed to percent？" Can you please elaborate it with desired output, it can be handwritten also. You can edit your question with the desired output.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo9yy.png)   Can you see the link?

Comment: No need to provide repetitive % sign in the y-axis ticks rather you can mention the unit as % within parenthesis. Your data should be in %.

Comment: Thank you! But Can I know what code can help if I want to change the data in %?

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1507852800, 1507939200, 1508025600, 1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 1508371200, 1508457600, 1508544000, 1508630400, 1508716800, 1508803200, 1508889600, 1508976000), class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Simulated = c(0.23375, 0.23175, 0.231, 0.2305, 0.2405, 0.24, 0.2385, 0.23675, 0.2355, 0.234, 0.23225, 0.23075, 0.2295, 0.2285), Measured = c(NA, 0.273, NA, NA, 0.21311677200277, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.229871184500008, NA, NA, 0.242, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
View(df)
library(foreign)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(hydroGOF)
library(zoo)

Simulated <- df$Simulated
Measured <- df$Measured
Date <- df$Date

ggof(sim=Simulated, obs=Measured, na.rm = TRUE, dates = Date, date.fmt = "%Y-%m-%d",,
     pt.style = "ts", ftype = "o", FUN,
     stype="default",
     gof.leg = TRUE, digits=2,
     gofs=c("ME", "MAE", "RMSE", "NRMSE", "PBIAS", "RSR", "rSD", "NSE", "mNSE",
            "rNSE", "d", "md", "rd", "r", "R2", "bR2", "KGE", "VE"),
     col = c("black", "red"))
```